# Дизайн spring boot приложения

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, архитектура

День добрый, хочу сделать приложение на spring boot, будет состоять из rest api для админки(сама админка предполагается на angular) и rest api торчащего наружу. Вот подскажите , как лучше это спроектировать , сделать одно приложение, разбить контроллеры по url типа /admin и /api? Но тут еще вопрос возник, хочу использовать swagger, как в нем можно разбить список api на 2 странички 1 для админа и 2 для api?
Или все же лучше сделать 2 приложения - 1 rest api для админки, 2 на внешний rest api?

Comment: Делайте всё в одном приложении. В сваггере информацию можно разбить на разделы с помощью нескольких `Docket`, в openApi с помощью `GroupedOpenApi` где указываются url'ы

Comment: в чем принципиальное отличие админского API от API торчащего наружу? Насколько они должны быть изолированы?

Comment: админское должно быть доступно только из внутренней сети

Comment: @МихаилБуркевич используйте nginx для таких разграничений, это куда удобнее чем 2 сервиса пилить на начальном этапе